# What do you call a person who does plating and casting in metal?

Tags: word-request

Our grandfather worked in a foundry doing plating and casting in metal. What job title includes these skill?

Comment: "Foundry worker"? Honestly, I don't know how well any one single title would encompass both plating and casting.

Comment: If he worked with molten metal it'd probably be a boilermaker or blacksmith.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest a **metallurgist**. Alternatively, **steelmaker**, **moulder**, **welder**, **tinsmith**.

From my understanding **metallurgist** involves both plating and casting, as well some elements of engineering. Other names are more specialized, and I included them into the roster hoping that one of them can ring a bell and somehow help the OP to decide which one fits better. I also must point out that I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: Any explanation of the difference between these terms and why you might prefer one over the other?

Comment: @ColleenV From my understanding *metallurgist* involves both plating and casting, as well some elements of engineering. Other names are more specialized, and I included them into the roster hoping that one of them can ring a bell and somehow help the OP to decide which one fits better. I also must point out that I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: I think if you [edit] your answer to include your understanding of each word instead of just providing a list, it would be a much better answer. Keep in mind that people other than the original author may come looking for an answer, so it helps to add more explanation.

Comment: @ColleenV Due to the lack of imagination I just attached my comment to the answer. Hopefully this counts.

Answer (score 2):

He could also be called a Foundryman.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foundryman

A person who plates metals is called a plater, and if he uses the processes of electrolysis to do so he may be called an electroplater.